# Task ContinueWith causing cross-thread exception despite UI context

Tags: c#, task, multithreading

I was under the impression that using Task's ContinueWith method with a UI context allows performing operations on UI elements without causing a cross-thread exception. However, I am still getting an exception when running the following code:

```
var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

Task<SomeResultClass>.Factory.StartNew(SomeWorkMethod).ContinueWith((t) =>
   {
      myListControl.Add(t.Result); // <-- this causes an exception
   }, context);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason you don't use `Invoke` to access the UI control ?

Comment: are you starting the task from the dispatcher's thread? If not that would explain it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different causes of cross-thread exceptions.

The most common one is that you try to modify the state of a control from the non-UI thread. And this is **not** the issue you're hitting.

The one you're hitting is that **controls must be created on the UI thread**. Your task is creating the control on a different thread and when you try to add this control to controls created on the UI thread you get the exception.

You need to separate out the work from the control creation to make this work. Try returning a `Func<Control>` rather than a `Control` and invoke this on the UI thread before adding it. Keep most of the work on the task thread but form a nice tight closure by returning the `Func<>` that just does the control creation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You were pretty much correct - my SomeWorkMethod was creating a user control which was creating its own controls. Even though this SHOULD have been done on the same UI thread (this wouldn't cause an exception if not using Tasks), when using this user control in the ContinueWith operation, it caused the exception. My ultimate solution was to use the UI context in the StartNew method AS WELL AS the ContinueWith method, which then worked.

Comment: Actually after thinking about this some more, it makes perfect sense that the user control created in the StartNew method would be in a separate thread - I somehow completely missed this, which is idiotic. Anyways, all is resolved :)

Answer (score 7):

Aside from the reasons and possible solutions Enigmativity told allready you can allways do something like this:

```
var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

Task<SomeResultClass>.Factory.StartNew(SomeWorkMethod).ContinueWith((t) =>
   {
      if (!myListControl.InvokeRequired)
         myListControl.Add(t.Result); // <-- this causes an exception
      else
         myListControl.Invoke((Action)(() => myListControl.Add(t.Result)));
   }, context);
```

(assuming this is WinForms)

if you want mor control refactor the add into a method and use the InvokeRequired inside the method to call itself inside the Invoke if needed:

```
private void AddToListControl(MyItem item)
{
   if (myListControl.InvokeRequired) 
   {
      myListControl.Invoke((Action)(() => AddToListControl(item)));
      return;
   }

   myListControl.Add(item);
}
```

What Enigmativity was hinting at is something like this:

```
var result =
   Task<Action>.Factory.StartNew(SomeWorkMethod).ContinueWith((t) =>
      {
         return () => myListControl.Add(t.Result);
      });

result.Result();
```

But IMHO this is just the same place you got from the start because you have to call the Result-Action on the right thread yet again.

Comment: Is it just me who see `.InvokeRequired` as a "code smell"? i.e. something you needed once as a quick fix and now use everywhere.

Comment: I really don't know - it's just this little pest you allways have to be aware if you write code against a UI - I tend to refactor it inside ViewModels and such so it's almost natural to me by now.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration! Enigmativity was pretty much correct in that there were some controls that were created that SHOULD have been created in the same UI thread, but for some reason aren't when using Tasks. I upped you tho, since this is useful info in other situations.